# Prove that $\lim_{h\to0}\frac 1{he^{\frac 1{h^2}}}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

I would like to prove that $$\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}\frac 1{he^{\frac 1{h^2}}}=0.$$

But L'Hopital's Rule doesn't seem to help, nor does the Sandwich Theorem. Any suggestions?

Comment: substitution $u = 1/h$.

Comment: There are in principle two cases to examine. If $h\lt 0$, set $x=1/|h|$.

Comment: @Yimin     Thanks! [][][]

Comment: @AndréNicolas Oh yes, thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\dfrac 1{he^{\frac 1{h^2}}}=\dfrac {\frac{1}{h}}{e^{\frac 1{h^2}}}\xrightarrow[h\to0^+]{}\dfrac{+\infty}{+\infty}$ L'Hôpital $\Rightarrow$

$\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0^+}\dfrac 1{he^{\frac 1{h^2}}}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac {-\frac{1}{h^2}}{-\dfrac{2e^{\frac 1{h^2}}}{h^3}}=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac {h}{2e^{\frac 1{h^2}}}=0.$

Do the same for the $\lim_{h\to0^-}$

Comment: I think $\lim_{x \to 0+}$ should be replaced by $\lim_{h \to 0+}$ .

Answer (score 1):

Set $x= 1/h$:

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} {1 \over h e^{1/h^2}} = \lim_{x \to \infty } {x \over e^{x^2}} = 0$$

as the limit of a continuous function $f$ obeys the rule
$ \lim_{x \to a}f(x) = f(a)$

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute, $h=\frac{1}{t}$,

then $$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{1}{he^{1/{h^2}}}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t}{e^{t^2}}=0$$

and similarly, $$\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{1}{he^{1/{h^2}}}=\lim_{t\to -\infty}\frac{t}{e^{t^2}}=0$$

Since , $$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{1}{he^{1/{h^2}}}=\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{1}{he^{1/{h^2}}}$$

therefore, $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{he^{1/{h^2}}}$ exists and equal to $0$

Comment: Thank you for your great answer.